# Why do we have to specify hrtimer_mode twice using hrtimers

Tags: c, linux, timer, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Why do we need to specify `hrtimer_mode` twice while using hrtimers:

1.Timer Initialization:

```
void hrtimer_init(struct hrtimer *timer, clockid_t which_clock,
                  enum hrtimer_mode mode);
```

2.Starting a timer:

```
void hrtimer_start(struct hrtimer *timer, ktime_t tim,
                   const enum hrtimer_mode mode);
```

What will happen if I specify different modes in both functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HRTIMER_MODE_REL` affects both the clock selection in `hrtimer_init()` and the interpretation of the timeout in `hrtimer_start()`.

If you initialize a CLOCK_REALTIME timer as absolute and later use a relative timeout, then the timeout might get affected by clock modifications (which, from the userspace point of view, violates POSIX).

Comment: I didn't get the second line of POSIX Violation. Can you please explain in more detail or provide some reference.

Comment: hrtimers are used to implement `timer_create()`, i.e., they are designed to conform to the POSIX behaviour.